# Macro that inserts code into control structure

Tags: c++, macros

I have a waitUntil macro defined as

```cpp
#define waitUntil(condition) while(!(condition)) delay(10);
```

Occasionally, I need code like updating a variable in that while loop. Given the definition of the macro, it is not usable, and I have to revert back to writing the while-loop and delay.

```cpp
while(!condition){
  counter++;
  delay(10);
}
```

Is there a way to re-write the macro to allow code in the loop body?

A better example is `#define FOR(count) for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)`

This is ok, because

```cpp
FOR(5){
  //body
}
```

expands into

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  //body
}
```

I can't do this with the while loop since that delay must be present.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the answers. Yes, I understand the preference for functions over macros in C++. Also, I get the standard for all-caps, but this is a very small codebase, and only 4 of us will really interact with it and we all know `waitUntil` is a macro.

While passing a function to it would work, I was looking for a way that didn't need the code to be passed into the macro. If that is the only option, it's ok; then a direct while loop is probably best.

Something that should do what I want is:

```cpp
#define waitUntil(condition) while(!(condition)){ delay(10);
```

Which should then be able to be used as

```cpp
waitUntil(counter > 4)
  counter++;
}
```

But this has clear issues.

Comment: There is probably some really slick way to do it that'll leave me and the maintenance staff scratching our heads for a while, then throwing it out in favour of something easier to debug. This is a time-waster loop, so it can afford to be slow. Pass the name of a function into `waitUntil` and call the function.

Comment: @user4581301  Here it is.  It leaves me scratching my head: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/mp/

Comment: A for loop allows arbitrary code and something that executes afterward.  So `#define waitUntil(condition) for(;!(condition);delay(10))` should do what you want, right?  (I haven't tested it)

Comment: 99% of the time writing a macro in c++ is a bad idea.

Comment: Here is an example of the for loop I suggested: https://onlinegdb.com/LeK3OPv9Y   And here is one with a while loop that uses the comma operator: https://onlinegdb.com/uQqle2qxo

Comment: @pm is right.  It is really hard to debug through code that uses macros - because they are expanded before the compiler even gets a look in they aren't part of the code the debugger knows about.  You are almost always better with a function.

Comment: but if you are going to use a macro, make sure everyone **knows** it's a macro with ALL_CAPS. I once ran into `strlen` implemented as a macro and it wasted half a day. Admittedly I was trying to get smart, but I'd have gotten away with it with a `strlen` function.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the while loop and comma operator solution looks great. Not what I was originally thinking of, but it will probably be what I end up using. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically want a macro that uses a while loop internally and can still execute arbitrary code followed by a delay then you need to put the delay into the while loop condition:

```
#define waitUntil(condition) while(delay(10),!(condition))
```

The comma operator make `delay(10)` execute first, followed by `!(condition)` (left to right executrion) - the last expression determines the result of the whole expression.

You can try it here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/uQqle2qxo

The downside is that `delay(10)` is executed at least once - even if the condition is already met.  If you use a for loop the condition can be checked before the loop executes and the delay can happen after the arbitrary code:

```
#define waitUntil(condition) for(;!(condition);delay(10))
```

You can try it here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/LeK3OPv9Y

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a macro for this. Here is a function template implementation:

```
template<typename C, typename F>
void waitUntilAndDo(C condition, F func) {
    while(!condition()) {
        func();
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

which can be called, e.g. as

```
waitUntilAndDo([&]{ return counter < 100; }, [&]{ counter++; });
```

---

You can also just do this with a single function argument of course:

```
template<typename C>
void waitUntil(C condition) {
    while(!condition()) {
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

called as e.g.

```
waitUntil([&]{
    /* something to do */
    return /* condition */;
});
```

with the caveat that this executes `/* something to do */` even if the loop condition is false from the beginning (which could of course also be resolved in the condition lambda, but wouldn't look nice).

---

Although just writing out the loop is probably clearer in any case.

Comment: As an added bonus, this is very likely to completely inline, making it better and easier to read, than trying to pull it off with a macro.